# Charge only the highest shipping class cost in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I am trying to get the shipping class associated with each line item for both simple and variable products, then find out which one has the highest cost and charge that only removing the rest of the shipping cost. It's for WooCommerce.

What I did-

1. Added two zones
2. Added two shipping class
3. Added price for both classes in the method
4. Set By class as the calculation method
5. Set the shipping class in the product variations

Edit: code so far added.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_method_by_class', 10, 2);

function custom_shipping_method_by_class($rates, $package)
{
    $class_costs = array();

    foreach ($package['contents'] as $item) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        if ($product instanceof WC_Product_Variable) {
            foreach ($product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id) {
                $term = wp_get_post_terms($variation_id, 'product_shipping_class');

                if (!empty($term)) {
                    $term = reset($term);
                    $class_costs[$term->term_id] = max($class_costs[$term->term_id] ?? 0, $rates["{$term->term_id}:$variation_id"]->cost);

                    var_dump($class_costs); // I get 0 here although I the variation has the shipping class set and the class has an amount set too.
                }
            }
        } else {
            $term = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_shipping_class');

            if (!empty($term)) {
                $term = reset($term);
                $class_costs[$term->term_id] = max($class_costs[$term->term_id] ?? 0, $rates["{$term->term_id}:$product_id"]->cost);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
        list($class_id, $product_id) = explode(':', $rate_key);

        if (!array_key_exists($class_id, $class_costs) || $class_costs[$class_id] !== $rate->cost) {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hi, sorry that I didn't add my code initially. Tried several versions. Added the latest one with a comment where it fails. Added some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any code as there is "Calculation type" setting option (select field) on each Flat rate, where you can select between *"Per class: Charge shipping for each shipping class individually"* or *"Per order: Charge shipping for the most expensive shipping class"*:

[image]

See the [Flat Rate shipping method WooCommerce documentation](https://woo.com/document/flat-rate-shipping/)

Comment: This works! Just out of curiosity, if we were to do this with code, what was wrong in my code? I noticed. Why the code could not get the shipping class and its corresponding price per line item which I tried?

Comment: I am not sure that the best hook for that is `woocommerce_package_rates` Then your code can be largely simplified and to get detailed shipping costs as you wanted, you need to go through the shipping method costs settings, as you can't get each shipping class cost via `$rates` variable for a shipping method… Then you also need to take into account the tax costs…

Comment: Any idea which hook might be a better pick for this as `woocommerce_package_rates` is not the correct one? I think I can take care of the codes if I know the hook. Tried `woocommerce_cart_loaded` but that didn't help much.